# How to do FTP transfer in background thread in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, ftp, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

I'm trying to do automated FTP transfer in a broadcast receiver using AlarmManager, and it's working very well on my HTC, but it's crashing on my friend's Galaxy S3. It seems to be an ICS issue, as there's a "Network on main thread" exception in LogCat when I simulate it.

It looks like I will have to use AsyncTask. Is it possible to implement AsyncTask in a broadcast receiver? I can't find anything on the web about it. Does anyone know?

Here's the relevant part of the method for the FTP download:

```
   public void getFTP(Context context)
 {
  //
  // Download config.txt file from server
  //
   FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

 try{

 ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));  
 ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
 ftpClient.login(user, pass);
 ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);

 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/config.txt"),8*1024);

 boolean status=ftpClient.retrieveFile("config.txt", bos);

 if(status){
     //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Downloaded config.txt!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     //toast.show();
     }
     else {
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot download config.txt!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();  
     return;
     }

 bos.flush();
 bos.close();

 ftpClient.logout();
 ftpClient.disconnect();

 }

 catch (IOException e){
     Toast.makeText(context,"Connection error!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return;
 }
```

It's called from the onReceive() method using

```
getFTP(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have called execute on an AsyncTask implementation from a broadcast receiver without issue. As long as task.execute() is called from your app's main thread it should be fine (which would be the normal case in a receiver).

But if you do have problems, you could also try wrapping your ftp session in a Runnable, then doing something like:

```
new Thread(new FtpRunnable()).start();
```

FWIW, here's some more info on [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). So that behavior isn't an *issue* per se, it's by design.